# Не могу унаследовать класс TelegramLongPollingBot

Tags: java, spring, telegram, maven, telegrambots

Решил я значит создать еще одного бота *(несколько у меня уже есть)*, но, вдруг вылезла ошибка, вернее ничего не вылезло, я просто не могу унаследовать класс **TelegramLongPollingBot**

Мой pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.VOITY</groupId>
        <artifactId>LIBRARY_BOT</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <name>LIBRARY_BOT</name>
            <description>VOITY_LIBRARY_BOT</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.telegram/telegrambots -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
        <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Работаю в eclipse, при попытке ввода

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
```

У меня красным загорается *org.telegram* и просит IDE добавить архив **telegrambots-6.1.0.jar**
После добавления при наведении на **TelegramLongPollingBot** пишет - *"Разрешение для типа org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.generics.LongPollingBot невозможно. В требуемых файлах .class на него есть косвенная ссылка"*
И предлагает настроить путь сборки 0_0

Повторюсь, мой не первый бот, понятия не имею что идет не так, все должно идти иначе, а идет криво, кто сталкивался подскажите что именно надо делать? Переустановить IDE ? Или это трудноуловимая ошибка какая-то или надо путь сборки настроить, но я не знаю как так как не сталкивался никогда

Answer (score 0):

Итак, попробовал на другом ПК и о чудо - получилось унаследовать без проблем!
Видимо проблема в eclipse надо переустанавливать, но это дело не хитрое)